# I can no longer reach Ubuntu Desktop and instead get "GNU GRUB VERSION2.03..."

Tags: boot, grub2

I am not able to reach my Ubuntu desktop because whenever I try to it automatically opens a window for booting the OS which I don't want to do.

The following display appears.

My problem is that, earlier this menu never showed up and it used to move straight to the desktop screen but I can no longer reach my desktop screen any more, why is this happening? And how can I go back to the normal situation again?

[image]

Comment: I guess u dont want this grub menu...but it is bootloader of Ubuntu...how is it not supposed to show up :/

Comment: Actually the OP is right, With Ubuntu only Grub is also there doing its job but usually doesn't appear unless with a key press.

Comment: How about a 5 second countdown timer that way memtest and old kernel versions can still be run. Also the OP is on 2.03 not 1.99 (grub2).

Comment: I have edited my question a bit, the problem is that even I don't understand why this is happening but I can no longer reach my desktop and do my work. Thanks for all the responses and help.

Comment: Did you follow the instructions below the bottom of the menu, i. e. did you “[p]ress enter to boot the selected OS” (the currently selected entry happening to be Ubuntu)? What happened? Once we establish that the boot process still works, we can find a way to get rid of the menu and boot straight to Ubuntu.

Comment: Can you press E and ss the boot config here?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post output of `cat /etc/default/grub` terminal command.

Comment: Highlight the `Ubuntu` entry by pressing `↓`/`↑` if needed (it should be highlighted by default) and press `Enter`. Alternatively, just don't touch the keyboard at all after powering on your computer and after a countdown of at most 10 seconds, it should boot automatically. The countdown gets stopped once you hit any key though.

Answer (score 0):

Choose Ubuntu from the grub menu with the arrow keys and hit enter.

Login to Ubuntu, open User Accounts, Unlock your account and flip the switcch for auto login.[image: UserAccounts]

If this doesn't solve your problem, drop me a comment with the details of what happened that you didn't expect.